# How do I do command line assertions without elm-test in Elm 0.18?

Tags: elm

I had dozens of Elm 0.17 programs for experimenting with the language. The scripts each featured simple assertions, and the program would execute and run all the assertions, and the program would succeed (process exit code 0) or fail (process exit code not 0). Here is an example:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import ElmTest exposing (runSuite, suite, defaultTest, assertEqual)
import List exposing (map)

boss = { name = "Alice", salary = 200000 }
worker = { name = "Bob", salary = 50000, supervisor = boss }
newWorker = { worker | name = "Carol" }

payrollTax : { a | salary : Float } -> Float
payrollTax { salary } = salary * 0.15


main = runSuite <| suite "Exploring records" <| map defaultTest
    [ assertEqual "Alice" (.name boss)
    , assertEqual boss worker.supervisor
    , assertEqual 7500.0 (payrollTax worker)
    , assertEqual boss newWorker.supervisor
    ]
```

Back in Elm 0.17, I would just run

```
$ elm make records.elm --output tests.js && node tests.js
```

And great, I'd see if the tests worked!

I finally decided to run `elm upgrade` to get to 0.18 and now (no real surprise) all those things are broken. Apparently, the whole concept of `elm-test` is now completely changed! Of course, `elm upgrade` did a nice job of updating my `elm-package.json`

```
    "dependencies": {
        "elm-community/elm-test": "4.0.0 <= v < 5.0.0",
```

but the new module does not have `ElmTest` and `runSuite` and friends anymore. I've read the docs and see that we now have `Test`, `Expect`, and `Fuzz`, which is fine. But it seems that now we are supposed to run

```
elm test init
```

and then

```
elm test
```

to discover and run all the tests. Instead of writing an app with `main`, we're now, I think, supposed to put tests in a test directory as modules exposing a `Test` object. Then we run `elm test`.

But I am not trying to run tests! I just want to write little scripts that make assertions about language features. I've done this in a couple dozen other languages and I find it a great way to learn.

How, then, in Elm 0.18, can I make a program that I can run with `elm make` or similar, that runs from the command line and has assertions? (I realize Elm is not for command line programs, but this was easy to do in 0.17, so how can I do something similar in 0.18?

Comment: I suggest you install an earlier version of elm-test. v4 added the new syntax but is really only in beta. v3 still works with 0.18 and has the hooks you want

Comment: Thanks, though the hook I am looking for is something similar to elm-test version 1.1, which had the module `ElmTest` with the function `runSuite : Test -> Program Never`. I can't find any function, even in elm-test 3.0.0, that produces a `Program` object. Thus I'm unable to run tests from a `main`. Am I missing something? Is there any way to produce a `Program` object and still use assertions?

Comment: whoops - apologies - I was writing from memory and see it is now `run emit` in v3

Comment: Who knew? I never heard about this, thanks. Looking through the Elm source code I did find the `TestProgram` type used in https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/master/tests/Main.elm but AFAICT this appears _nowhere_ in public documentation. Wonder if we are not supposed to use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using an old version of that library. runSuite, assertions, etc are from 1.0.0 version and the current version is 4.0.0+.

I recomend you read the [Upgrading guide from 0.17 to 0.18](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.18.md)
and [the docs for elm-community/elm-test latest](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/elm-test/latest)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed. The question is what is the equivalent of `runSuite` in 4.0.0. The beauty of `ElmTest.runSuite` in 1.0.0. was that that function returned a `Program` value, so I could use it from `main`. I loved that!! Now with 4.1.0, I _don't see anything that returns a Program`. So as far as I can tell the updates to this package got rid of something I liked. Do you know of any way I can run assertions from `main`? If the answer is no, so be it, but I really hope they did not throw that away. :) I just can't find it.

Comment: The new version of this library is more complex and powerfull. The goal is to separete your tests from the application.
You can get a TestProgram if you use Test.Runner.Node from [node-test-runner package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/node-test-runner/latest).
Also it's interesting to see [how elm-core performs its tests](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/tree/master/tests)